# “npm run serve” problem on Vue.js progect

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Recently, I am learning to use Vue.js. When I use the "**npm run serve**" command to run the project, the project reports the following error:

```
# ERROR Failed to compile with 2 errors 01:27:41

# This relative module was not found:

# \* ./src/main.js in multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.7:8081/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/ dev-server.js ./src/main.js, multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server. js ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.7:8081/sockjs-node ./src/main.js
```

According to the methods on the Internet, I have tried to delete `node_modules` and `package_lock.json`, and use "npm install" to reinstall dependencies, but this error still exists.

The package.json lilkes this:

```
{
  "name": "forum",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "buefy": "^0.8.8",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So uh do you have a main.js file in your src folder?